# How to make the ViewPager don't destroy pager which has been instantiated

Tags: android, android-viewpager

setOffscreenPageLimit is not useful, because the count is not specified.

And how to disable ViewPager's preload. I can't setOffscreenPageLimit to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) as it retains all Fragments in FragmentManager till user can return to it.